# Create dynamic folder with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic

First of all thank you for checking over my questions.
I have a MySQL database with data like ID, name, etc. and a file which shows data depending on what the ID of user is. My link is like this:(its in a subdomain)

http://crm.example.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?id=12

I want to make SEO friendly URL for the user to give to their clients, so its going to get their name from the database depending on their ID, and make a dynamic folder like:

http://crm.example.com/saloon/name

which this url will showing the content of:
crm.example.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?id=(ID depends on what name was given, and the name is going to be unique)

I tried some other ways which were on stackoverflow with htaccess writing but I kept getting internal server error etc. So waiting for your reply.

Thanks in advance,
MrCodexCY

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess commands? Internal server errors are simply bad syntax when messing with .htaccess.

Comment: I dont have the code I have been putting before, so if you can please provide me with a new .htaccess code to do it so I try it and give feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

You'd do this with [URL rewriting](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/). If you're encountering errors, you should check the Apache error logs.

Comment: Just to mention that the PHP script will still have to pull the data from the database based on the "name" value, which shouldn't be a problem since it is described as being unique. Just making sure before you try to magically make the name turn into an integer ID using just the mod_rewrite. :P

Comment: This is the one tutorial I wrote but I still had problems. Should my code look like this?

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^saloon/?$ folder1/folder2/index.php [NC,L]

And if yes, where should I put the .htaccess? in the main folder of the subdomain crm.example.com ?